# Tar error while installing cpanel on fresh Ubuntu VPS

Tags: tar, vps

I have a VPS based on ubuntu linux. Currently this is fresh server where we have installed LAMP but now I am trying to install Cpanel & WHM. For this, I am following below command:

```
cd /home && curl -o latest -L https://securedownloads.cpanel.net/latest && sh latest
```

Using the above command, I am getting below error:

[image]

When I try to install tar using this command **sudo apt-get install tar** then server is saying newest version is already installed and it is already in bin/tar.

Can someone please help me what I am missing or doing wrong? I just want to install Cpanel and WHM on my Ubuntu VPS

Comment: The problem seems to be that the script is trying to use `yum` (a package manager for RedHat systems) - so either the version you downloaded is not appropriate for Ubuntu or it is mis-identifying your OS

Answer (score 1):

Cpanel is not designed to be used on Ubuntu systems.  It won't work.

See https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/84Docs/Installation+Guide+-+System+Requirements#InstallationGuide-SystemRequirements-Operatingsystems for supported systems.